# How to convert a ruby text paragraph to string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

My application allows the administrator to define SQL templates scripts, that users can apply to data structures. The templates are stored within a database textfield, and will be merged with the data structure metadata.

A template statement looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #{@target.code} ( 
    #{@target.getColList('ORACLE', 'typed')} 
)
```

and I plan to evaluate it to get the desired SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE DSD_TEST (
AHVN13_1 number,
ALTER_MT_ERFUELLT_1 number,
CANTONS_2_1 varchar2(32),
POPULATION_TYPE_1 varchar2(32)
)
```

but actually the template statement (of Postgres text field) returns the following:

```
"CREATE TABLE \#{@target.code} ( \r\n\#{@target.getColList('ORACLE', 'typed')} \r\n)"
```

I found out that I can get rid of the new line using `task.statement.gsub("\r\n", '')`, but I cannot get rid of the special character '\ '.

How can I build this template so it can be evaluated?

Comment: Have you tried to evaluate it? Isn't the \ before each `#` just the Ruby interpreter telling you that everything inside `#{}` is code to be evaluated? If I print the string after the newlines are removed I get `CREATE TABLE #{@target.code} ( #{@target.getColList('ORACLE', 'typed')} )"`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but the expression `eval( '"CREATE TABLE \#{task.code} "')` returns `"CREATE TABLE \#{task.code} "`. Then `eval( '"CREATE TABLE \#{task.code} "'.gsub("\\",''))` finally works.